# What does the warning related to mpool ucp_am_bufs means in a MPI running program?

Tags: c++11, mpi

I am running a C++ program that runs on several "processors" using MPI (mpirun (Open MPI) 4.0.1), a C++ lib that allows instances of a program to be launched on different processors and to communicate together.

**For those familiar with the MPI librairy** : what would you recommand me to do or to check to deal with the following error message ? Is this message refering to something very specific ?

A clue I have is that it could come from a blocking command (BSend, Brecv) waiting for a message from some of the nodes I am using, I know the code reaches its end then probably some functions are still waiting messages. Well it's just my guess because I could not find any information about "mpool" in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

ERROR MESSAGE :

[1650458693.767260] [node010:51793:0]          mpool.c:38   UCX  WARN  object 0x2ba6f718cf40 was not returned to mpool ucp_am_bufs

Post-scriptum : The code is thousand lines long, therefore I am not asking help to delve into it but rather advices to interpret this error message if it is a generic one. Thnx !

Comment: UCX is a library generally used by Open MPI to indirectly use an Infiniband network. The message could be a bug in UCX, or Open MPI or a side effect of a bug in your application. Make sure you use the latest UCX and Open MPI (built on top of that latest UCX) and try again. If the issue persists, ask Open MPI (either via the mailing list or open a github issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation I figured out where the error came from.
I decided to reply myself to help anyone who would dig out a similar mistake. The question has been raised on the GitLab of MPI but never has been answered.

Long story short my "master" processor was MPI_Sending informations to the "slaves" processors. At the very same moment my "master" was sending these informations, all the slaves were turned-off, hence the "master" being angry not being answered.

Henceforth when MPI_Sending datas, I will (and I would recommand) check the status of the slaves CPUs.